# How to check if app is closed in notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

In my app, I have an activity A that opens Activity B. B then opens notifications. Upon clicking the notification it needs to resume the app. This is where the problem is. The code below resumes activity B and works. But this assumes that the app is still running even if minimized.

But if the user closes the app, and then click on the notification, it will open activity B, and then crash because certain things are not set up for B to run since A was not run.

Basically I need a way to check if the app is running, and if its not, then open A, else open B.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, SpeciesScreen.class);
    notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Scan Complete")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this..
notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
START THIS ACTIVITY WITH NEW TASK ALWAYS.

Comment: Do i remove the other flags?

Comment: Actually I changed my problem to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539021/is-there-an-android-intent-that-opens-class-if-activity-running-else-open-app

Answer (score 0):

You can do such work by adding try catch in your activity B. Use try and catch in activity B and if the activity is not initialized correctly in the catch section use an intent to run activity A.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
       initForm();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       Intent i = new Intent(context, A.class);
       startActivity(i);
       finish();
   }
}
```