# Is there an android intent that resumes the app or opens it again?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, push-notification

In my android app, this code will open/resume a activity

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, SpeciesScreen.class);
    notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Scan Complete")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

The behavior is that if the app is running and minimized on SpeciesScreen, it will resume it, if its already running or exited, then it will attempt to open SpeciesScreen. Note: SpeciesScreen is not the default activity that runs initially.

But what I want is (when clicking on the notification that runs the intent):

If its minimized (regardless of what activity its currently on), just resume it, don't open another activity.

If its running (regardless of what activity its currently on), do nothing.

If its closed, then open the app as if you clicked on the icon on the home screen.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could make a "middle man" activity, so to speak, who's intent you give to the notification that decides what state your app is in and then starts that activity? I haven't tried something like this before so it may not work, or may produce behavior you do not find acceptable. Either way let me know :-)

Comment: Well right now I did a hacky way, which is on the on start event of the activity i said to open, if it doesn't have intent data, then close it and open the default activity. This makes it work exactly like how I wanted, but feels too dirty.

Comment: Maybe you should post that code on Code Review, if you had it working, but in a hackish way. They'll fix it right up.

Comment: correction: this hack way doesn't work completely right.

Comment: ok i fixed the hack way, and posted it below.

Comment: Perhaps try posting your hack method at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the hack way I got, maybe someone can improve on it.

```
public Boolean paused = false;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    paused = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    paused = false;
}

private void setUpScreen() {
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        // ran normally
    } else {
        // opened from notification

        finish();

        // open default activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

in the async

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<CompareResult> compareResults) {


    if (context.paused) {
        showNotification();
    }
}

private void showNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(context, SpeciesScreen.class);
    notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Scan Complete")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 
}
```